# Unhandled Error in Selenium with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, phpunit

I am using Selenium with PHPUnit and Laracast integrated library to work with.

The thing is that it appears a weird error when I run the tests and I haven't found it anywhere.

The code is the following:

```
<?php

use Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Selenium as SeleniumTestCase;
use Laracasts\Integrated\Services\Laravel\Application as Laravel;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\App;
use App\Models\Role;

class SeleniumTests extends SeleniumTestCase
{

    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';

    use Laravel;

    /**
    *
    * Creates a user with email $email and password $password
    *
    * @param string $email    Email of the user
    * @param string $password Password of the user
    *
    * @return User
    */
    private function createAdminUser($email, $password)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = rand(1000000000, 999999999999)." user ".rand(1000000000, 999999999999);
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = \Hash::make($password);
        $user->save();

        $adminRole = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();

        $user->attachRole($adminRole);

        return \App\Models\User::find($user->id);
    }

    /**
    * @test
    * Test a login of a registered user
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function testLoginOK()
    {
        $email = 'test@user.com';
        $password = 'us3rP4ssW0rd';

        $this->createAdminUser($email, $password);

        $this->visit('auth/login')
             ->type($email, 'email')
             ->type($password, 'password')
             ->andSnap()
             ->press('Continue')
             ->seePageIs('dashboard');
    }
```

And the error I am receiving is:

```
{
  "sessionId": null,
  "status": 13,
  "state": "unhandled error",
  "value": {
    "message": "GET \/auth\/login\nBuild info: version: '2.48.1', revision: 'd80083d', time: '2015-10-08 21:11:00'\nSystem info: host: 'homestead', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown",
    "suppressed": [

    ],
    "localizedMessage": "GET \/auth\/login\nBuild info: version: '2.48.1', revision: 'd80083d', time: '2015-10-08 21:11:00'\nSystem info: host: 'homestead', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown",
    "buildInformation": null,
    "cause": null,
    "systemInformation": "System info: host: 'homestead', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'",
    "supportUrl": null,
    "class": "org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException",
    "additionalInformation": "\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown",
    "hCode": 138828459,
    "stackTrace": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ]
  },
  "class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response",
  "hCode": 1122669771
}
```

As extra info: If I put `protected $baseUrl = 'http://{my_development_url}';` instead of `protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';` everything works as expected, but I need the code to work on Scrutinizer, so I can't do it like that.

If instead of accessing `auth/login` I access `/` it appears a dashboard with buttons, so I guess Selenium is working.

Does anyone have a clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a lot of time and learning I'll explain a little more my case and I'll get to the conclusions.

I am using Laravel 5 with Selenium. Since I am using selenium and not Laravel's IntegratedTests, I had to setup a test domain. I was using nginx, so I changed my .env file and created a new domain. Since I am developing plenty of projects in the same Homestead, I couldn't use the default localhost for that.

So, conclusions:

- I had to create another domain in my nginx to test it
- I had to change my .env file with the testing database
- I had to setup Selenium to work headless by doing:

  - `sudo apt-get install xvfb firefox`
  - `DISPLAY=:0 xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 2560x2560x24" java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.1.jar`

After that you'll be able to run your tests properly

Answer (score 0):

> everything works as expected, but I need the code to work on Scrutinizer, so I can't do it like that.

It looks like your solution is an environment type. You're going to want to use the env() helper method here.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->baseUrl = env('TEST_BASEURL', 'http://{my_development_url}');
}
```

Then simply add this line to your .env:

TEST_BASEURL=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

---

Here's where to find additional docs: http://laravel.com/docs/master/#environment-configuration.

Comment: The thing is that I need to configure the whole thing in Scrutinizer, right? Set the host, configure a nginx server... right?

Comment: You can just have the default details work in scrutinizer.